# How to incorporate a UISearchController into new (iOS8) UISplitviewController

Tags: ios8, uistoryboard, uisplitviewcontroller, ios-universal-app, uisearchcontroller

I try to build a simple app based on the UISplitViewController template from Xcode 6 for universal apps (with Storyboard and CoreData/NSFetchedResultsController). This app should also provide a search bar for the MasterViewController. Unfortunately, Xcode 6 provides no InterfaceBuilder element for the UISearchBar/UISearchController combo (only the depreciated UISearchBar/UISearchDisplayController).

In the iOS Developer library, Apple provides the "Table Search with UISearchController" example, but this is not based on the UISplitViewController and supports only iPhone.

My problem is, that I'm not able to show the detail view on the correct ViewController under all circumstances. I tried to transfer the approach from the Apple example project to the UISplitViewController template. In this, one is encouraged to show the search results in a separate UITableViewController subclass (ResultsTableViewController) and use this as the searchResultsController of the UISearchController. I was not able to create a scene in InterfaceBuilder for this setup so I had to add these manually in code.

The problems begin when I click on a table cell of the ResultsTableViewController. This vc is not part of the scene in InterfaceBuilde and I don't know how to add it to the SplitViewController setting correctly. The biggest problem is the weird behavoir of the iPhone 6 Plus and the UISplitViewController. In portrait mode it behaves like an iPhone and doesn't seem to have a SplitViewController and only uses a NavigationController to which I push my DetailViewController. In landscape mode it behaves like an iPad with SplitViewController were I have to get the second ViewController of the SplitViewController `childControllers` and push the DetailViewController on this one.

Now it happens, when I start in portrait mode and switch to landscape mode that the DetailViewController is all gone, showing gray space where the DetailVC should be. It seems, when going to portrait mode, the DetailViewController gets kicked from the SplitViewController (or the SplitViewController gets kicked at all in favor for the iPhones NavigationController setup). When switching back to landscape the SplitViewController is initialized again but without proper initialization of the DetailViewController.

Is there any template or suggestion on how to correctly implement search capabilities on a universal UISplitViewController?

Cheers
Björn